# Read file bytes using MemoryMappedFile

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

How can I read file bytes using `MemoryMappedFile` and put it into `byte[]` array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to read a portion of the file, something like this should work:

```
long offset = 0x10000000; // 256 megabytes 
long length = 100; 
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\Test.data"))
    {
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = CreateViewStream(offset, length))
        {
            byte[length] bytes;
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)length);
        }
    }
```

If you want to read the entire file, you really shouldn't be using a `MemoryMappedFile` object in the first place.

Comment: Note that `stream.Read` may read less than `length` bytes into `bytes`.

Comment: @dtb Good point, that wasn't clear.  I updated my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: No.  Sorry.  I don't have much experience with the Compact Framework.  If, as it seems, `MemoryMappedFile` is not supported by the compact framework, you'd probably just need to use a standard `FileStream` and it's `Seek` method to jump around in the file.

Comment: @Kostadin oops, forgot include your name in my last comment so that you'd receive notification of my response...